# Woocommerce Login Form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just know you guys are a knowledgeable lot, and can possibly help me. Iv’e looked everywhere on the net, and cannot seem to find anything, the things I do find simply don’t work.

It’s in regards to Woo Commerce.

What I want to achieve is basically, separating the registration page from the login. Currently we have to use the my account short code, which places both Login and Register forms on the same page, and the register form, is just Email Address.

What I want to do, is to have the same page, but instead of the register form. A button that says “new users register here” and this sends them to a register page. On that page, I would use the Ninja Forms plugin to have a register form.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would try display none the register elements. You could use javascript or html to add a button with a link to the page with the ninja form.